# Submit do form dentro de uma view modal me redireciona para a página da view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, modal

Tenho um projeto MVC. A View **Home/Index** carrega a View **Usuarios/Create** em forma de uma modal do bootstrap. Porém, meu `<input type="submit" />` me redireciona para o endereço da view **Usuarios/Create**. Eu queria que aplicação permanecesse na View **Home/Index** com a modal aberta. Como posso fazer isso?

Este é o código da minha View **Usuarios/Create** que é carregada como modal na **Home/Index**:

```
@model Project.Models.Usuario

@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">CADASTRO</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-12">Seu nome: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "campo" })</div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-12">Seu melhor email: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "campo" })</div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-12">Defina sua senha: @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Senha, new { @class = "campo" })</div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Senha, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-12">Digite a senha novamente: <input type="password" name="name" value="" class="campo" /></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-12"><input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="CADASTRAR" class="botao botao-principal" /></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
}
```

E é assim que eu abro a modal na **Home/Index**:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal"></div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".cadastrar").click(function () {
            $("#modal").load("../Usuarios/Create", function () {
                $("#modal").modal();
            })
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: https://softdevpractice.com/blog/asp-net-core-mvc-ajax-modals/

Comment: Deu certo alguma resposta João?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode direcionar o post da sua página dizendo pra onde ele vai ao dar o submit.

```html
@Html.BeginForm("YOUR_ACTION_NAME", "YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME", FORM_METHOD)
```

Esse método têm vários overloads, mas vamos ao mais comum
ActionName – Nome da ação a ser executada.
ControllerName – Nome do controller a ser executado. 
FormMethod – Especifica a forma que será enviada os dados, através de POST ou GET.

Exemplo:

```js
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```